# Incrementing attributes in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I want to figure out how to increment a player's health without writing 225 lines of Datapack code. I cannot find any way to do this. I've tried :

```
execute at @a run execute unless score @p custHealth matches 1 run attribute @p generic.max_health base set Health @p
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command (amplifier is no. of hearts)

> `/effect give @a health_boost <duration> <amplifier>`

Or for permanent use:

> `/attribute @a minecraft:generic.max_health base set 2`

In this case 2 means 1 heart, so you enter e.g. 60 for 30 hearts.

Comment: so the first command doesnt work, the syntax is wrong. the second command does not answer my question